# What is the difference between UseStaticFiles() and UseFileServer() in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am confused between these two. What and when should be used in an ASP.NET web application?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

UseFileServer includes UseStaticFiles, UseDefaultFiles, and optionally UseDirectoryBrowsing. The average site only needs UseStaticFiles.